# Active Record and Rails - Help to configure the correct association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm looking for something very easy, I did it in the past but I stoped coding for several months and I forgot almost everything :(

I have a many to many association
- One agency provide several services
- One service is provided by several agencies

My models

Agency.rb

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :agency_services  
 has_many :services, through: :agency_services
end
```

Service.rb

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :agency_services
 has_many :agencies, through: :agency_services
end
```

Agency_service.rb

```
class AgencyService < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :service
 belongs_to :agency
end
```

Then, I have a seeds.rb where I create the data in my database

```
a = Agency.new(name:"A Agency", description:"Best agency")
a.save

seo = Service.new(name:"Seo", description:"Improve Google result")
seo.save

agency_service = AgencyService.new(agency_id:1, service_id:1)
agency_service.save
```

In the Rails Console

```
seo.agencies
```

Return an array with the agency providing the "seo" service, which is nice (here the "a" agency)

But, when I try to reverse the search and find all the services provided by the "a" agency, I can't find it

```
a.services
```

Return

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

In my mind, by doing a.services I should have an array of all the services provided by agency_id:1 (the "a" agency), so in this case the "Seo" service.

Do you see what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you :)

Edit : It's strange because now the

```
a.services
```

Return the array of the service provided by the agency
And

```
seo.agencies
```

Return

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I don't understand ...

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be set up:

```
#app/models/agency.rb
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :agency_services
   has_many :services, through: :agency_services
end

#app/models/agency_service.rb
class AgencyService < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :agency
   belongs_to :service
end

#app/models/service.rb
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :agency_services
   has_many :agencies, through: :services
end
```

This will allow you to use the following seeds:

```
a = Agency.new(name:"A Agency", description:"Best agency")
a.save

seo = agency.services.new(name:"Seo", description:"Improve Google result")
seo.save

#agency_service should be populated automatically
```

--

This should work, considering you have the tables set up as below:

[image]

Comment: Oh agency_service doesn't need to be filled by doing that, thank you so much ! I'll do that, much better.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, your model `AgencyService` have foreign key `agence_id`. It should be `agency_id`

```
a = Agency.new(name:"A Agency", description:"Best agency")
a.save

seo = Service.new(name:"Seo", description:"Improve Google result")
seo.save

agency_service = AgencyService.new(agency_id:1, service_id:1)
agency_service.save 

seo.agencies
a.services
```

I hope this would help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly it's not working, even with the right foreign key.

Comment: what is the results of `a.id` and `agency_service.agency_id` ?

Comment: Both return "1" But now it's working, both a.services and seo.agencies. Very strange but problem solved, thank you so much for you help !!